# Google Cloud DLP Custom Info type for Image Inspection

Tags: java, google-cloud-dlp

Was trying [Cloud Dlp Image Redaction](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/concepts-image-redaction) for removing sensitive content.

Google Doc mentions that we can redact image based on custom infotype but not able to find how to use custom infotype for redaction

Sample codes support for text inspection, tried similar thing for image inspection but was not able to get to a result

Answer (score 1):

They are supported within the InspectConfig.

```
{
  "inspectConfig": {
    "customInfoTypes": [
      {
        "dictionary": {
          "wordList": {
            "words": [
              "dogs",
              "hedgehogs",
              "fish"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "byteItem": {
    "data": "yourimage"
  }
}
```